# Celery vs crontab to call DB shell, which is better to add regular update data into django model database?

Tags: python, django, shell

I have made a Django app to display some stuff, the content of this app comes from my web scraping script. So the data is keep growing.

So there are methods to update data in database:

1. I know I can run crontab job to call a python script to read a file then use python manage.py shell to update data, but I am afraid that I cannot get log and handle exception easily.
2. Using Celery to run data in background to write data to DB.
3. Using database tools.(Not in my consideration)

Is there is better method to add incremental data when data is very big? any of them is welcomed.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to take celery or use crontab in this particular case is quite an opinionated choice. Both solutions should work fine.

Celery is far more powerful in general and (once configured) will allow you to do more stuff like using async tasks, etc. But to get it you will have to configure and then manage it. It's not hard but anyway you will have to spend some to to get it work.

I often use cron for simple projects because it's much more simple and doesn't require any additional efforts to use it. Seems like in your case it would sufficient too.

At last, asking your question :) if you would prefer cron you should use custom management commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/. This would allow you not to write .sh scripts. Crontab would look like this in that case:

`0 0 * * * /path/to/project/python /path/to/project/manage.py your_custom_command_name`

Comment: I just notice south module，how about writing migrate manually then use south vs db shell directly？

Comment: I would say that you don't even need DB shell. Custom management command is like a regular view (just without request variable) so you can use anything that you need like models or any other django stuff. South is primarily used for migrations (changing model fields etc.) so I doubt you need it.

Comment: I will have a try, thanks for your help:)